# Throwing/Catching AuthenticationException in dropwizard

Tags: java, dropwizard

I have a simple dropwizard app. Right now when a user tries to login with 
invalid credentials, it just keeps popping up the login box again (in a 
browser client). 
I want to be able to throw an exception, return a JSON letting the user 
know that authentication failed.

I tried the following:

```
@Override
 public Optional<SimplePrincipal> authenticate(BasicCredentials credentials) 
throws AuthenticationException {
 DPSLookup dps = new DPSLookup(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.
getPassword(), ldap);
 if (!dps.dpsLookup()) {
                   throw new InvalidCredentialException("Access Denied");
                }
               else { 
                 SimplePrincipal user = new SimplePrincipal(credentials.
getUsername());
                 return Optional.of(user);
                }
  }
```

And then I have an InvalidCredentialException class:
public class InvalidCredentialException extends AuthenticationException {

```
public InvalidCredentialException(String message) {
super(message);
}

}
```

however I get a 500 Response error now with the following exception:

```
WARN  [2016-05-03 14:09:49,982] 
io.dropwizard.auth.basic.BasicCredentialAuthFilter: Error authenticating 
credentials
! bns.gwtd.dpm.auth.InvalidCredentialException: Access Denied
! at 
bns.gwtd.dpm.auth.SimpleAuthenticator.authenticate(SimpleAuthenticator.java:50) 
~[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
bns.gwtd.dpm.auth.SimpleAuthenticator.authenticate(SimpleAuthenticator.java:24) 
~[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
io.dropwizard.auth.basic.BasicCredentialAuthFilter.filter(BasicCredentialAuthFilter.java:47) 
~[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:132) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:68) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:318) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:29) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:43) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:38) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:256) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:219) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:240) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:51) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:159) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
ERROR [2016-05-03 14:09:49,983] 
io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a 
request: 122bf997f092f693
! javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
! at 
io.dropwizard.auth.basic.BasicCredentialAuthFilter.filter(BasicCredentialAuthFilter.java:74) 
~[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:132) 
~[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:68) 
~[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197) 
~[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:318) 
~[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:29) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:43) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:38) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:256) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:219) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:240) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:51) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:159) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) 
[gwtd-auth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
! at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way here is to have InvalidCredentialException extend [NotAuthorizedException](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.12/jersey/javax/ws/rs/NotAuthorizedException.html), Jersey understands anything extending WebApplicationException and converts them into appropriate HTTP responses instead of leaving them to get handled on the server. Since InvalidCredentialException already supports a message you might be better off throwing that directly.